# Should I stop the geth node during hard-fork?

Tags: go-ethereum, hardforks, istanbul

As the countdown on https://ethernodes.org/istanbul, should I need to stop my geth node before hard-fork? Or I could continue to syncing during hard-fork.
Thanks alot.

Comment: You don't have to. You just need to run the latest client (Geth/Parity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're running a version that supports the fork (the latest version), there is no need to stop it.